# Finding the duration based on some conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 variables x,y,z,a which will be recorded in my database at same time. I need to find the duration for which `x or y or z !=0 and a>8`. Here it will be from `01-01-2019 01:04:32 to 01-01-2019 01:06:13`.
I am trying to get all occurrences and duration for which the above condition is satisfied. This is something like a gaps and islands problem.

output like : `01-01-2019 01:04:32 to 01-01-2019 01:06:13  for 00:01:41`. I also try to show it day wise or week wise in case if I have more data.

```
v1                  v2  v3
01-01-2019 01:03:56 x   1
01-01-2019 01:03:56 y   2
01-01-2019 01:03:56 z   3
01-01-2019 01:03:56 a   4.5
01-01-2019 01:04:32 x   3
01-01-2019 01:04:32 y   2.1
01-01-2019 01:04:32 z   6
01-01-2019 01:04:32 a   8
01-01-2019 01:06:13 x   9
01-01-2019 01:06:13 y   3
01-01-2019 01:06:13 z   2
01-01-2019 01:06:13 a   9.56
```

Comment: Please update with the expected output

Comment: A dataframe like this with three columns... when condition stared,when it ended  and the duration 01-01-2019 01:04:32  01-01-2019 01:06:13 00:01:41

Answer (score 0):

This code below identifies when your conditions are met.  How are you getting that "01-01-2019 01:04:32 01-01-2019 01:06:13 00:01:41" should be your result?  Your sample dataframe would indicate otherwise as 01:03:56 also matches your criteria on x, y, and z.

```
# Flag when conditions are met
df$s <- ifelse( (df$v2 == 'x' & df$v3 != 0 ) | (df$v2 == 'y' & df$v3 != 0 ) | (df$v2 == 'z' & df$v3 != 0 ) | (df$v2 == 'a' & df$v3 > 8) , 1, 0) 

View(df)
```

---

Using this data

```
# Create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
    v1 = c(
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:03:56"), 
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:03:56"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:03:56"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:03:56"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:04:32"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:04:32"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:04:32"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:04:32"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:06:13"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:06:13"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:06:13"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:06:13")),
    v2 = c('x','y','z','a','x','y','z','a','x','y','z','a'),
    v3 = c(1,2,3,4.5,3,2.1,6,8,9,3,2,9.56)
)
```

Comment: `v1 v2   v3 s
1  2019-01-01 01:03:56  x 1.00 1
2  2019-01-01 01:03:56  y 2.00 1
3  2019-01-01 01:03:56  z 3.00 1
4  2019-01-01 01:03:56  a 4.50 0
5  2019-01-01 01:04:32  x 3.00 1
6  2019-01-01 01:04:32  y 2.10 1
7  2019-01-01 01:04:32  z 6.00 1
8  2019-01-01 01:04:32  a 8.00 0
9  2019-01-01 01:06:13  x 9.00 1
10 2019-01-01 01:06:13  y 3.00 1
11 2019-01-01 01:06:13  z 2.00 1
12 2019-01-01 01:06:13  a 9.56 1`. I am not suppposed to get this

Comment: I also want to check 4 variables with respect to time and not with respect to the condition alone

Comment: I'd recommend modifying your original question to show the specific output you want in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we could `group_by` `v1` and `filter` the groups based on criteria mentioned so that we only have groups in which we are interested. Take only `distinct` values of `v1` and create groups of 2 rows which will represent start and end time to be subtracted from each other. We use `spread` to get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  filter((all(v3[v2 == 'x'] != 0) | all(v3[v2 == 'y'] != 0) | 
          all(v3[v2 == 'z'] != 0)) & any(v3[v2 == 'a'] >= 8)) %>%
   distinct(v1) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(group = rep(c("col1", "col2"), length.out = n())) %>%
   tidyr::spread(group, v1) %>%
   mutate(diff_col = col2 - col1)


#  col1                col2                diff_col     
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       
#1 2019-01-01 01:04:32 2019-01-01 01:06:13 1.683333 mins
```